# Limit of $(\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(t\right)}-1+t-\sin\left(t\right),\:\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(t\right)}-1-t+\sin\left(t\right))$ = $0$ - Is my proof good?

Tags: limits, vector-spaces, differential

The original limit is:
$\left(\cos t-1+t-\sin t,\:\cos t-1-t+\sin t \right)$
But I changed it to get all for $\sin t$:

$\left(\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}-1+t-\sin t,\:\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}-1-t+\sin t\right)$

Limit of this, as $t$ goes to $0$.

I said it like that:
We will get basically $\lim_{t\to 0}  \frac{(0,0)}t $ and since its $0$ by $t$, so its $0$.

Is it true? because I don't really get $0$ identity... it is super close to $0$, but not really.
Is there any way to prove it's equal to $0$? Or is my proof good?

Comment: How did you get $\frac{(0,0)}{t}$ from the original limit with no fraction?

Comment: what do you mean without fraction? from the expression I got, I just did T=0 at the upper expression. reached (0,0) - close to it @bananapeel22

Comment: It is not good at all, wherever this $\frac{(0,0)}t$ comes from. There are many ways to prove your limit is $(0,0),$ but you really seem to need to train on simpler exercises.

Comment: Oh I dont need anymore. I managed to solve it.
I just seperated it to cos(t)-1 fracture by t, sin(t) by t, and got 0 good. thanks though :)